# Retrieve data from ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying retrieve all the records from by SQL statement which is grouped by Year. I can retrieve the first set using rs.getString(1) and rs.getString(2) for the year and the number but when I try rs.getString(3) I get an SQLException error. I am looking to grab the first index of the rows and second index to get the year and numbers, respectively.

The query executed on the database returns the following:

[image]

Code snippet:

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

String sql = "SELECT Year, SUM(all_motor_vehicles) AS allmotor\n" +
          "FROM Vehicle\n"
        + "WHERE Year IN (2005, 2006, 2007)\n"
        + "GROUP BY YEAR;";

pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = pst.executeQuery();

amount = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2)); //get the result
yearFromDB = rs.getString(1);
System.out.println(amount + " " + yearFromDB); //result is printed

dataset.addValue(amount, allMotorVehicles, yearFromDB);

System.out.println(rs.getString(3) + " " + rs.getString(4)); //Gives me an error
```

Output:

```
345433 2005
SQLException error
```

Comment: YOu only have two columns. Calling "getString(3)" implies there is a 3rd column which there isn't

Comment: What did you want or expect to get from `rs.getString(3)` and `rs.getString(4))`? BTW prefer `getInt()` over `getString()` for whole numbers so you need not parse in Java.

Comment: A result set is initially positioned **before** the first row, so you have to call `next()`. Also, you may want to review how you log exception, because the message as shown is likely not the actual exception message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (rs.next()) {
    amount = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2)); //get the result
    yearFromDB = rs.getString(1);
    System.out.println(amount + " " + yearFromDB); //result is printed
}
```

ResultSet contains multiple rows of data. To go to the next row, you need to call rs.next() method as above.

What you are doing by calling rs.getString(3) is basically trying to access fourth column of the first row. As fourth column is not present, you are getting error.

Comment: Should you not use hasNext and next in conjuction? This will work. But that's how you iterate a collection or result.

Answer (score 2):

Just to remove confusion because of  rs.getString(1)/ rs.getString(2). You can directly use the column name in place of number as below.

```
    while (rs.next()) {
        amount = Integer.parseInt(rs.getString("allmotor")); //get the result
        yearFromDB = rs.getString("Year");
        System.out.println(amount + " " + yearFromDB); //result is printed
    }
```